# Como executar scripts no powershell

Tags: windows, script, bash, powershell

Eu tenho um script extrair.sh que faz algumas coisas.
Tenho outro script powershell.sh que faz a chamada apenas do powershell.
E dentro do powershell.sh eu puxo o extrair.sh pra ele executar o script dentro do powershell.
Mas quando o script powershell.sh roda que abre o powershell, ele para por ali mesmo...

Meu segundo cenário foi colocar o comando powershell antes do script iniciar no script extrair.sh, mas o resultado foi o mesmo...

Aí minha dúvida é:
Como eu consigo chamar o powershell e executar meu script?

Comment: você poderia colocar um exemplo dos códigos dos scripts que você quer executar?

Comment: e como executar no linux??

Comment: @PauloBoaventura, https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arquivos de script powershell normalmente usam a extensão `.ps1` e seguem a [especificação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-important-powershell-concepts?view=powershell-6) da liguagem.

Seguindo a premissa que seu script é escrito em powershell e sua máquina tem o powershell [instalado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6).

Você pode utilizar o `cmd.exe` e digitar:

```
powershell seu-script.ps1
```

Usando o [`powershell.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/getting-started/starting-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6) e digitar:

```
.\seu-script.ps1
```

Alem disso powershell tem uma ferramenta  ISE (Ambiente de Script Integrado) `Powershell_ISE.exe`.

Resposta na thread em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035193/how-to-run-a-powershell-script/2035209

Comment: E como executar no Ubuntu ???

Comment: @PauloBoaventura vc tem que instalar seguindo o seguinte link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 1):

O PowerShell vem restrito e somente é possivel executar um script clicando com o botão direito e pedindo para executar pelo PowerShell, ou como o amigo acima informou execultando o PowerShell e chamando o Script já dentro do PowerShell.

Para mudar a politica de execução do PowerShell podemos usar o seguinte comando como Administrador:

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
```

Para verificar como esta a restrição use o seguinte:

```
get-executionpolicy
```